# Testing code which uses Realm addNotificationBlock

Tags: ios, swift, testing, realm

Is there a way to configure `Realm` so that notifications callbacks (registered with `addNotificationBlock`) are fired synchronously?  In particular, I want this behavior in tests.

Since the callbacks are asynchronous, they can't be used in tests.  Therefore, it's necessary to inject a dependency which wraps notification registration in production, while instead injecting a dependency which mimics the behavior in tests.

That's not a great solution though, since it a) requires much more code and b) that code is making assumptions about Realm, such as how to construct a `RealmCollectionChange`.

If it can't be made to fire synchronously, maybe someone has a suggestion for a better way to test code which relies on `RealmCollectionChange`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expectation(description:)` and `waitForExpectations(timeout:handler:)` to test async methods as follows.

```
func test() {
    let q = DispatchQueue(label: "Q")

    q.async {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(TestObj())
        }
    }

    let e = expectation(description: "Notification fired")

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let token = realm.addNotificationBlock { (notification, realm) in
        print("notification block")
        e.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 2.0, handler: nil)
    token.stop()
}
```

Comment: While this solution works, it's still not ideal, unfortunately.  Tests require much more coordination with implementation details, especially if test subjects are far removed from the notification block, as with integration tests.  You need to dependency inject an `XCTestExpectation` and then you also need to know when we *should* be waiting on it.  Also, it opens the possibility of false-positive passing tests when you *should* have waited on a notification block, but didn't, and a test passes due to that.